# Remote access to router via OMCI and TR-069

Tags: router, isp, gateway

My ISP ships to me a router that they can remote manage via OMCI and TR-069.

I am not familiar at all with these methods. How can I monitor or even block these accesses? It feels wrong to have random employees at the ISP be able to do whatever they want with the most important device I own.

Comment: Why not become familiar with these methods first, then you can make an informed decision.

Comment: That's not what you asked. You asked how to monitor or block… which is not going to happen. Requests for learning resources are off-topic. These protocols are very easy to search.

Comment: Your comment "which is not going to happen" suggests you have some knowledge about this. Care to share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not trust your ISP (which is totally reasonable!), just must not use hardware your ISP lends you. Or, if that is not possible, install an additional firewall/router behind the ISP device.

There's also the problem with firmware updates, which are often delayed or not coming at all for branded devices.

Reliably disabling remote management will in general not be possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Between these 2 solutions : 1) installing an additional firewall/router behind the ISP device and 2) replacing their device entirely, how would they compare ? I know I can do either (I called them to confirm). 2 is a little bit more work, but how much better is it security-wise?

Comment: Fewer devices mean less energy consumption and fewer points of failure. Port forwarding is another thing that is more complicated with two routers. Security is pretty much the same, of course.

Comment: Right, but I feel it will be easier for me to continue to use the ISP as a modem, and just place behind it my own router. I am actually surprised to hear both setups are as secure. I expected that removing entirely the ISP device would be more secure? Can you elaborate a bit, so that I can understand better?

Comment: I use a second router behind the provided router. Otherwise if there is a problem ISPs tend to blame everything on a wrongly configured router.

Comment: @DevShark Your router is either “at the perimeter”, or, if ISP router in front is breached (by ISP or third party)… at the perimeter. No difference whatsoever.

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of PON it is common to have a two-box setup. The fiber is terminated in an ONU. The ONU has a UTP cable running to a router.

It this scenario, it should absolutely make no difference whether the ISP has full control over your ONU (not the router) or not. While the ONU is inside your house, you can consider it to be part of your ISP network. Obviously your ISP has full control over their network and can inspect any traffic that is forwarded over it.

If the router and ONU are combined in one box things get a little more fuzzy. Your ISP may be able to see wifi connections, dhcp leases and lan-lan traffic if that traffic passes the router.